# /page/2/ redirect to 404 when get parameters

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and make a filter form in the `category.php` page and get parameters with `get_query_var`, my problem is in the Pagination when the user filters a parameter and wants to go to page 2, it redirects it to 404 instead of the category page (https://hexrom.com/roms/gameboy-advance/page/2/?title=pokemon). the problem is `/page/2/?title=pokemon` doesn't load the `category.php`

Here is the code:

Code in `function.php`:

```
add_action('init','wpse46108_register_param');
function wpse46108_register_param() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('title');
    $wp->add_query_var('genre');
    $wp->add_query_var('region');
    $wp->add_query_var('console');
    $wp->add_query_var('top');
}
```

And I have a custom query in `category.php` page:

```
if (!empty(get_query_var('title'))) {
    $ti = get_query_var('title');
}
if (!empty(get_query_var('genre'))) {
    $ge = get_query_var('genre');
}
if (!empty(get_query_var('region'))) {
    $reg = get_query_var('region');
}
if (!empty(get_query_var('console'))) {
    $con = get_query_var('console');
}
if (!empty(get_query_var('top'))) {
    $top = get_query_var('top');
}


if (!empty($ge) && empty($reg)) {
  $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'wpse18703_title' => '' . $ti . '',
 'cat' => $catid,
 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
 'meta_query' => array(
 array(
  'key' => 'genre',
  'value' => '' . $ge . '',
  'compare' => '='
)
));
}

query_posts($args);
```

Update:
I also tried `WP_Query` to load the post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have enough result on query "title=pokemon" to have more than one page ?
On your first page, we can't see the pagination section, so there is no possibility to get to the page 2 from the page 1 of title=pokemon.
In that case, we want to have a 404 error on this page : https://hexrom.com/roms/gameboy-advance/page/2/?title=pokemon

I think your problem is on your searchbar form. the `<form>` tag containing your searchbar has the wrong `action` value.
The `action` value should be the url of your page **WITHOUT** the current pagination.
With that, when you are on /page/2 of any query, doing a different research will lead you to the first page of results.

Comparing to the other site you linked in comments, if you go on https://romspure.cc/roms/3ds/page/2/ and then look for "pokemon" in searchbard, you will be redirected to page 1 of query "pokemon". And you see that there is no page 2 for this query either.
But if I manually try to go to a second page, I have a 404 error, which is normal : https://romspure.cc/roms/3ds/page/2/?search=pokemon&g=&r=&d=&p=

Your goal is to replace this form tag :

`<form class="" method="GET" action="https://hexrom.com/roms/gameboy-advance/page/2/">`

by this one :

`<form class="" method="GET" action="https://hexrom.com/roms/gameboy-advance/">`

on this page : https://hexrom.com/roms/gameboy-advance/page/2/